# Spring Data MVC + Thymeleaf: update entity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am trying to update certain attributes of an entity with a thymeleaf form.

I made a controller that adds a DTO to the model. That way I don't have to send unnecessary employee attributes to the view.

This setup gives me an error when trying to edit an attribute of Employee (clicking the edit button on the form):

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='employeeDTO'. Error count: 2
```

Apparently my setup doesn't work because of the Date and the List objects I have in my DTO.

How do I solve this? Do I need to write some converters? How do I do that?

Isn't there an easier way to edit an entity's attributes? I mean an easier way than `@SessionAttributes("employee")`, DTO's, Mapper, Converter, ... This seems such straightforward functionality but I can't get it to work and I have the feeling I'm adding to much stuff (DTO's, mappers, converter?, ...) just to be able to edit an attribute of an entity.

**Entities:**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Car> carHistory = new ArrayList<Car>();

    // constructors

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private CarStatus status;
    private String plate;

    // constructors
    // getters & setters

    public enum CarStatus {
        FREE, ORDERED, IN_USE, INACTIVE
    }

}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeService(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public void updateEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeRepository.saveAndFlush(employee);
    }
}
```

**Employee DTO:**

```
public class EmployeeDTO implements Serializable{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    private List<Car> carHistory;

    // getters & setters
}
```

**DTO mapper:**

```
public class EmployeeMapper {

    public static Employee mapEmployeeDTOToEmployeeObject(EmployeeDTO dto, Employee employee){
        employee.setFirstName(dto.getFirstName());
        employee.setLastName(dto.getLastName());
        employee.setBirthDate(dto.getBirthDate());
        employee.setCarHistory(dto.getCarHistory());
        return employee;
    }

    public static EmployeeDTO mapEmployeeToEmployeeObject(Employee employee){
        EmployeeDTO dto = new EmployeeDTO();
        dto.setFirstName(employee.getFirstName());
        dto.setLastName(employee.getLastName());
        dto.setBirthDate(employee.getBirthDate());
        dto.setCarHistory(employee.getCarHistory());
        return dto;
    }
}
```

**Conroller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/manage")
@SessionAttributes("employee")
public class ManageEmployeesController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @RequestMapping("/employees")
    public String manageEmployee(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("employees", employeeService.getAllEmployees());
        return "manage-employee";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String employeeDetails(@PathVariable("employeeId") Long id, Model model){
        Employee emp = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        model.addAttribute("employee", EmployeeMapper.mapEmployeeToEmployeeObject(emp));
        return "manage-employee-details";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEmployeeDetails(@PathVariable("employeeId") Long id, EmployeeDTO employeeWithNewValues){
        Employee currentEmployee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(id);
        employeeService.updateEmployee(EmployeeMapper.mapEmployeeDTOToEmployeeObject(employeeWithNewValues, currentEmployee));
        return "redirect:/fleetmanager/employees";
    }
}
```

**Thymeleaf form:**

```
<form role="form" method="post" th:object="${employee}">
    <h2>Personal details</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:readonly="true" th:value="*{firstName}" th:field="*{firstName}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:value="*{lastName}" th:field="*{lastName}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Birthdate:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:value="*{birthDate}" th:field="*{birthDate}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="car : *{carHistory}">
            <td th:text="${car.plate}">Plate</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using dates in model objects bound to form fields, you need to specify the format in which the dates are submitted in the HTTP request.  You need to define a `PropertyEditor` for this.

```
class DateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {
  private static final String FORMAT = "MMMMM dd, yyyy"; // Or any valid date format.

  public String getAsText() {
    return getValue() != null
             ? new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT).format(getValue())
             : null;
  }

  public void setAsText(final String value) {
    try {
      setValue(new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT).parse(value));
    }
    catch (final ParseException e) {
      // Log error.
    }
  }
}
```

Then, configure your controller to use this editor.

```
public class ManageEmployeesController {
  @InitBinder
  public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateEditor());
  }
}
```

Now, whenever Spring MVC encounters a form-bound field of the type `Date`, it will use this `PropertyEditor` for the conversion to and from `String`.